# Vim ErrorFormat question for Gradle compiler plugin

Tags: regular-expression, makeprg

I am trying to fix a compiler plugin for Gradle. Gradle generates error messages of the type:

```
:compileJava/file/path/Main.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    public static ABC abc;
                  ^
  symbol:   class ABC
  location: class Main
/file/path/Main2.java:291: error: incompatible types: com.whatever.N cannot be converted to com.another.N
... and so on
```

All error messages except for the first one are properly parsed with this error format string

```
CompilerSet errorformat=
  \%E%f:%l:\ error:\ %m
```

The problem is that Gradle prepends a target name (in this case `:compileJava`) to the first error message. My question is: how do I specify that :compileJava (and maybe some other :compileTarget) strings can be optionally included at the beginning of the error message?

If I were to write a regexp in a more common format, this would look similar to:

```
\(:compileJava|:compileTarget]\)?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest doing it like this:

```
let &errorformat =
    \ '%E%\m:%\%%(compileJava%\|compileTarget%\)%f:%l: error: %m,' .
    \ '%E%f:%l: error: %m,' .
    \ '%Z%p^,' .
    \ '%-G%.%#'
```

Proof:

```
cgetexpr [':compileJava/file/path/Main.java:52: error: cannot find symbol',
    \ '    public static ABC abc;',
    \ '                  ^',
    \ '  symbol:   class ABC',
    \ '  location: class Main',
    \ '/file/path/Main2.java:291: error: incompatible types: com.whatever.N cannot be converted to com.another.N' ]
echomsg string(getqflist())
```

Output:

```
[{'lnum': 52, 'bufnr': 3, 'col': 19, 'valid': 1, 'vcol': 1, 'nr': -1, 'type': 'E', 'pattern': '', 'text': 'cannot find symbol'},
 {'lnum': 291, 'bufnr': 4, 'col': 0, 'valid': 1, 'vcol': 0, 'nr': -1, 'type': 'E', 'pattern': '', 'text': 'incompatible types: com.whatever.N cannot be converted to com.another.N'}]
```

Comment: Wow! It worked! Thanks so much! If possible, can you please explain the solution a bit more? As i understand, dots (.) are used for string concatenation, right? And instead of escaping all spaces etc., errorformat string is surrounded by quotes. But what does `%\%%` sequence mean? And what is the difference between `let &errorformat` and `CompilerSet errorformat`? (the latter does not work with the efm string specified above).

Comment: @siphiuel If you read the docs, you will find that the errorformats are tried consecutively until one matches. The first entries have highest priority. Thus the solution by @lcd047 consists of 4 entries, where the first one matches errors that contains the `compileJava` or `compileTarget` lines. The second matches the other errors, the third defines a "pointer line" and the end of en error message, and the final entry says to ignore every remaining lines.