# Make: Nothing to be done for 'build'

Tags: makeprg

I am using a Gradle compiler plugin for Vim. I run `:compiler gradle` and then `:make build`, and Gradle build is executed and error results properly parsed (many thanks to @lcd047 answering my [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4048/vim-errorformat-question-for-gradle-compiler-plugin/4052?noredirect=1#comment5891_4052)). The problem is that after I fix some errors and re-run the build to check if they were properly fixed, `make` tells me that

```
make: Nothing to be done for `build'.
```

If i restart Vim, i can re-run the build again.

Seems that it's looking for some timestamp that is not changed? How do I tell make to re-run the build anyway?

Comment: What does your 'makeprg' look like (`:set makeprg?`)? What command exactly is executed when you do `:make build`?

Comment: @jjaderberg - thank you. Seems that `makeprg` was set to `make` instead of `gradle` for some reason. Everything works fine now

Comment: Solved by comment from @jjaderberg

Comment: @siphiuel I think you did something with `makeprg`, but what? Could you post what you did to fix it as an answer? That was other people will be able to find it and benefit from it :-)

Comment: Added a proper answer. Thanks for putting this in order. I must admit that first i didn't properly understand what fixed it exactly:). But comments pointed in the right direction. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by comment from @jjaderberg. The problem is related to the `compiler` command. To quote Vim's help:

```
6. Selecting a compiler                                 compiler-select

                                                :comp :compiler E666
:comp[iler][!] {name}           Set options to work with compiler {name}.
                                Without the "!" options are set for the
                                current buffer.  With "!" global options are set.
```

Now, i was using `:compiler gradle` instead of `:compiler! gradle`, hence had `makeprg` properly set in one buffer only. Switching to a different buffer changed its value to the default, which is simply `make`.